# Subroutine with OPEN statement called from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, io, fortran

I have a Fortran subroutine which somewhere in the code has some I/O statements for output purposes:

```
 OPEN(16, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL.txt", 
1   action = "WRITE", status = "replace", IOSTAT=ios)
 IF (ios.EQ.0) THEN 
     WRITE(16,*)  something
```

I associate it with a program that uses it to make some calculations.

Now this works when I use a single core of my CPU. If I run it using more than one core I get an unknown error and the program ends abruptly. When the program ends I just get a message saying that an error occurred in the subroutine.

The error for me is related with the fact that while one core might be opening the file and writing information to it another core might want to do the same and this might cause the error. What do you guys think?

---

What worked for me:

```
                cpuid = 1
                WRITE(filename, '(a25,i2.2,a4)') 
     1           "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL",cpuid,".txt"
                OPEN(16,FILE=filename,
     1   action = "WRITE", status = "replace", IOSTAT=ios)
                IF (ios.EQ.0) THEN 
                    GOTO 601
                ELSE
  602               cpuid = cpuid + 1
                    WRITE(filename, '(a25,i2.2,a4)') 
     1           "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL",cpuid,".txt"
                    OPEN(16,FILE=filename,
     1   action = "WRITE", status = "replace", IOSTAT=ios1)
                    IF (ios1.EQ.0) THEN
                        GOTO 601
                    ELSE
                        GOTO 602
                    ENDIF
                ENDIF
  601           WRITE(16,*)  something
```

Comment: You ought to include said error message, but your intuition is probably right. You can always try adding `mpi_id` to the unit and appending the same number to the file: `unit=16+mpi_id` and `write(filename,'(a11,i2.2,a4)')"failureUEL.",mpi_id,".txt"`.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Thanks! Can you elaborate a little bit on the `write(filename,'(a11,i2.2,a4)')"failureUEL.",mpi_id,".txt"`. `filename`can be the `unit`? and should there be `//` to continue the syntax or it is not needed? Thanks!

Comment: That line means that you are writing `failureUEL.`,`mpi_id`,and `.txt` to the character `filename` (length of `len=17`). You would need `//` if you were concatenating strings, but you have two strings and an integer, so that's not an option. If you defined an integer `lun=16+mpi_id` then your open statement would be `open(unit=lun,file=filename,<options>)` where `<options>` is the rest of your stuff there.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Just a thing that I'm thinking: can I open files with the same path but with different file units? If not then I need to create a string made of: nstring = `"C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL",mpi_id,".txt"`. Is this syntax ok? Thanks

Comment: @jpcgandre You were given code to do that in the first comment, which you then asked about in your reply to that comment.  If `nstring` is a character type with enough storage for the string, then `write(nstring, '(a25,i2.2,a4)') "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL",mpi_id,".txt"`

Comment: OK! I got it now. Thanks

Comment: Just one more thing.... How do I get `mpi_id`? By calling `MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ID, iErr)`? Thanks!

Comment: Actually my main program uses multiple threads (1 node multiple cores) so maybe I cannot use `mpi_id`.... any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem depends on the kind of parallelization library you are using.

If you parallelized your code with OpenMP, I would suggest to perform the I/O by a single thread, with a `SINGLE` pragma

```
!$OMP SINGLE
open(16, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL.txt", &
  action = "WRITE", status = "replace", IOSTAT=ios)
if (ios.EQ.0) then
     write(16,*)  something
endif
!$OMP END SINGLE
```

If you parallelized your code with MPI, you have to write one file per process

```
write(numfile, '(i10)') myrank 
open(16, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/failureUEL."//trim(numfile)//".txt", &
  action = "WRITE", status = "replace", IOSTAT=ios)
if (ios.EQ.0) then 
     write(16,*)  something
endif
```

with `myrank` the rank of the process in the communicator you are using, and `numfile` a `character(len=*)`, for example.

You could also chose to use a parallel I/O library to write a single file (MPI-IO, Parallel HDF5, Parallel NetCDF...).

Comment: Hi! Can you please guide me to get `myrank`? Do I need to `CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, iErr)`? Thanks

Comment: Actually my main program uses multiple threads (1 computer node multiple cores of the same cpu) so maybe I cannot use any of your methods... suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @jpcgandre Yes, you will get myrank with the MPI_Comm_Rank() subroutine. As for your second comment, could you please specify more precisely how your code is parallelized? If you speak of "multiple threads", it might mean that you are using an OpenMP approach, but without more precisions about your code, I cannot say more. It could be also useful to know your compiler options.